# How can improve this algorithm to optimize the running time (find points in segments)

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, divide-and-conquer

I'm given 2 integrals, the first is the number of segments (Xi,Xj) and the second is the number of points that can or cant be inside those segments.

As an example, the input could be:

```
2 3
0 5
8 10
1 6 11
```

Where, in first line, 2 means "2 segments" and 3 means "3 points".
The 2 segments are "0 to 5" and "8 to 10", and the points to look for are 1, 6, 11.
The output is

```
1 0 0
```

Where point 1 is in segment "0 to 5", and point 6 and 11 are not in any segment. ***If a point appears in more than one segment, like a 3, the output would be 2.***

The original code, was just a double loop to search the points between segments. I used the Java Arrays quicksort (modified so when it sorts endpoints of segments, sorts also startpoints so start[i] and end[i] belong to the same segment i) to improve the speed of the double loop but it isnt enought.

The next code works fine but when there's too many segments it gets very slow:

```
public class PointsAndSegments {

    private static int[] fastCountSegments(int[] starts, int[] ends, int[] points) {
        sort(starts, ends);
        int[] cnt2 = CountSegments(starts,ends,points);
        return cnt2;
    }

    private static void dualPivotQuicksort(int[] a, int[] b, int left,int right, int div) {
    int len = right - left;
    if (len < 27) { // insertion sort for tiny array
        for (int i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j > left && b[j] < b[j - 1]; j--) {
                swap(a, b, j, j - 1);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    int third = len / div;
    // "medians"
    int m1 = left  + third;
    int m2 = right - third;
    if (m1 <= left) {
        m1 = left + 1;
    }
    if (m2 >= right) {
        m2 = right - 1;
    }
    if (a[m1] < a[m2]) {
        swap(a, b, m1, left);
        swap(a, b, m2, right);
    }
    else {
        swap(a, b, m1, right);
        swap(a, b, m2, left);
    }
    // pivots
    int pivot1 = b[left];
    int pivot2 = b[right];
    // pointers
    int less  = left  + 1;
    int great = right - 1;
    // sorting
    for (int k = less; k <= great; k++) {
        if (b[k] < pivot1) {
            swap(a, b, k, less++);
        } 
        else if (b[k] > pivot2) {
            while (k < great && b[great] > pivot2) {
                great--;
            }
            swap(a, b, k, great--);
            if (b[k] < pivot1) {
                swap(a, b, k, less++);
            }
        }
    }
    // swaps
    int dist = great - less;
    if (dist < 13) {
       div++;
    }
    swap(a, b, less  - 1, left);
    swap(a, b, great + 1, right);
    // subarrays
    dualPivotQuicksort(a, b, left,   less - 2, div);
    dualPivotQuicksort(a, b, great + 2, right, div);

    // equal elements
    if (dist > len - 13 && pivot1 != pivot2) {
        for (int k = less; k <= great; k++) {
            if (b[k] == pivot1) {
                swap(a, b, k, less++);
            }
            else if (b[k] == pivot2) {
                swap(a, b, k, great--);
                if (b[k] == pivot1) {
                    swap(a, b, k, less++);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // subarray
    if (pivot1 < pivot2) {
        dualPivotQuicksort(a, b, less, great, div);
    }
    }

    public static void sort(int[] a, int[] b) {
        sort(a, b, 0, b.length);
    }

    public static void sort(int[] a, int[] b, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        rangeCheck(a.length, fromIndex, toIndex);
        dualPivotQuicksort(a, b, fromIndex, toIndex - 1, 3);
    }

    private static void rangeCheck(int length, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        if (fromIndex > toIndex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("fromIndex > toIndex");
        }
        if (fromIndex < 0) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(fromIndex);
        }
        if (toIndex > length) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(toIndex);
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int[] a, int[] b, int i, int j) {
        int swap1 = a[i];
        int swap2 = b[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        b[i] = b[j];
        a[j] = swap1;
        b[j] = swap2;
    }

    private static int[] naiveCountSegments(int[] starts, int[] ends, int[] points) {
        int[] cnt = new int[points.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < starts.length; j++) {
                if (starts[j] <= points[i] && points[i] <= ends[j]) {
                    cnt[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, m;
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        m = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] starts = new int[n];
        int[] ends = new int[n];
        int[] points = new int[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            starts[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            ends[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            points[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        //use fastCountSegments
        int[] cnt = fastCountSegments(starts, ends, points);
        for (int x : cnt) {
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        }
    }
```

I believe the problem is in the CountSegments() method but I'm not sure of another way to solve it. Supposedly, I should use a divide and conquer algorithm, but after 4 days, I'm up to any solution.
I found [a similar problem in CodeForces](http://codeforces.com/contest/430/problem/A) but the output is different and most solutions are in C++. Since I have just 3 months that I started to learn java, I think I have reached my knowledge limit.

Comment: You have to tell the maximum number of segments and points, for such online-judge like question, it should be provided?

Comment: Segments & points are between 1 and 50,000 inclusive.

Comment: Will the segment overlap?

Comment: Yes they can overlap and Segment=(a,b) range is -10^8<= ai <=bi<=10^8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation similar to @Shole's idea:

```
public class SegmentsAlgorithm {

    private PriorityQueue<int[]> remainSegments = new PriorityQueue<>((o0, o1) -> Integer.compare(o0[0], o1[0]));
    private SegmentWeight[] arraySegments;

    public void addSegment(int begin, int end) {
        remainSegments.add(new int[]{begin, end});
    }

    public void prepareArrayCache() {
        List<SegmentWeight> preCalculate = new ArrayList<>();
        PriorityQueue<int[]> currentSegmentsByEnds = new PriorityQueue<>((o0, o1) -> Integer.compare(o0[1], o1[1]));
        int begin = remainSegments.peek()[0];
        while (!remainSegments.isEmpty() && remainSegments.peek()[0] == begin) {
            currentSegmentsByEnds.add(remainSegments.poll());
        }
        preCalculate.add(new SegmentWeight(begin, currentSegmentsByEnds.size()));
        int next;
        while (!remainSegments.isEmpty()) {
            if (currentSegmentsByEnds.isEmpty()) {
                next = remainSegments.peek()[0];
            } else {
                next = Math.min(currentSegmentsByEnds.peek()[1], remainSegments.peek()[0]);
            }
            while (!currentSegmentsByEnds.isEmpty() && currentSegmentsByEnds.peek()[1] == next) {
                currentSegmentsByEnds.poll();
            }
            while (!remainSegments.isEmpty() && remainSegments.peek()[0] == next) {
                currentSegmentsByEnds.add(remainSegments.poll());
            }
            preCalculate.add(new SegmentWeight(next, currentSegmentsByEnds.size()));
        }
        while (!currentSegmentsByEnds.isEmpty()) {
            next = currentSegmentsByEnds.peek()[1];
            while (!currentSegmentsByEnds.isEmpty() && currentSegmentsByEnds.peek()[1] == next) {
                currentSegmentsByEnds.poll();
            }
            preCalculate.add(new SegmentWeight(next, currentSegmentsByEnds.size()));
        }
        SegmentWeight[] arraySearch = new SegmentWeight[preCalculate.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (SegmentWeight l : preCalculate) {
            arraySearch[i++] = l;
        }
        this.arraySegments = arraySearch;
    }

    public int searchPoint(int p) {
        int result = 0;
        if (arraySegments != null && arraySegments.length > 0 && arraySegments[0].begin <= p) {
            int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arraySegments, new SegmentWeight(p, 0), (o0, o1) -> Integer.compare(o0.begin, o1.begin));
            if (index < 0){  // Bug fixed
                index = - 2 - index;
            }
            if (index >= 0 && index < arraySegments.length) { // Protection added
                result = arraySegments[index].weight;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SegmentsAlgorithm algorithm = new SegmentsAlgorithm();
        int[][] segments = {{0, 5},{3, 10},{8, 9},{14, 20},{12, 28}};
        for (int[] segment : segments) {
            algorithm.addSegment(segment[0], segment[1]);
        }
        algorithm.prepareArrayCache();

        int[] points = {-1, 2, 4, 6, 11, 28};

        for (int point: points) {
            System.out.println(point + ": " + algorithm.searchPoint(point));
        }
    }

    public static class SegmentWeight {

        int begin;
        int weight;

        public SegmentWeight(int begin, int weight) {
            this.begin = begin;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
-1: 0
2: 1
4: 2
6: 1
11: 2
28: 0
```

EDITED:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SegmentsAlgorithm algorithm = new SegmentsAlgorithm();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int m = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        algorithm.addSegment(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
    }
    algorithm.prepareArrayCache();
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        System.out.print(algorithm.searchPoint(scanner.nextInt())+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Your codes works fine, but I need to prove it with test cases. How 'd you adapt the  2D array[][] segments to take input from Scanner like this: {{1st, 2nd},{ 3rd, 4th}, {5th, 6th}......?

Comment: @Nooblhu Edited, It is adapted for Scanner.

Comment: Not sure why, its throwing ArrayIndexOutofBounds at searchPoint method: result = arraySegments[Math.abs(index)].weight; when invoked in System.out.print(algorithm.searchPoint(scanner.nextInt())+ " "); (using testcase of the question)

Comment: The OutofBounds error is fixed but Im not sure why the results are not ok Example: For segments (0, 5) (-3, 2) (7, 10) Points: 1 and 6: The result should be 2 0 (because 1 is in (0,5) and (-3,2) and 0 isnt in any segment), but it outputs 0 0

Answer (score 3):

Given the constrains by OP, let `n` be the # of segments, `m` be the number of points to be query,  where `n,m` <= 5*10^4, I can come up with a `O(nlg(n) + mlg(n))` solution (which should be enough to pass most online judge)

As each query is a verifying problem: ***Can the point be covered by some intervals, yes or no***, we do not need to find which / how many intervals the point has been covered.

Outline of the algorithm:

1. Sort all intervals first by starting point, if tie then by length (rightmost ending point)
2. Try to merge the intervals to get some **disjoint**  overlapping intervals. For e.g.  (0,5), (2,9), (3,7), (3,5), (12,15) , you will get (0,9), (12,15). As the intervals are sorted, this can be done greedily in `O(n)`
3. Above are the precomputation, now for each point, we query using the disjoint intervals. Simply binary search if any interval contains such point, each query is `O(lg(n))` and we got `m` points, so total `O(m lg(n))`

Combine whole algorithm, we will get an `O(nlg(n) + mlg(n))` algorithm

Comment: If segments are merged in 2. and overlapped, how can I count how many segments does the point intersects? Should I merge the points in 2. also? I assume that, so in 3 i search for points with binary search. I'm not sure my lvl of java is high enough to convert this 3 points in code, but I have an starter point

Comment: No, you mix it up. This method works provided that you DO NOT need to know how many segments the point is intersecting, but only "YES" or "NO".    And in 2, that's the preparation for 3, no points are considered, you only try to make the input data into some more favorable form (disjoint & sorted intervals), Then you start to query the point one by one, using this transformed data.  Yes in point 3 for each point we use binary search as I said, you may read lower_bound() or upper_bound() in C++ (not sure if Java got similar built in functions)

Comment: Sorry, I think I picked an input and output example that didnt specify that I had to count if the point appears in more than one segment. I've just modified that detail.

Comment: @Nooblhu so you have changed your OP, it's a total different question...

Comment: Sorry, I didnt really changed that option, check my code, it does count segments. But I tried to pick an easy example and it just confused the output I was expecting

Comment: Well I was confused by your output example then as it was 0 = not covered, 1 = covered before you edit. Anyway, if you have to count the number of intervals in such constrains, the only way I can think of is using segment tree, which still gives around O(m lg(n)) solution

Comment: I think I've done some improvements but I'm stuck in the sorting of the 2d element of the intervals. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135702/how-to-sort-an-array-of-segments-int-left-int-right-in-a-ascending-order-but